# Miracast receiver with touch input return

Tags: wifi-direct, chromecast

TLDR: Is there a software developed yet to act as a Miracast reciever that will return touch responces?

I have a fleet of touch screens that use HDMI and USB cables into staff laptops for lessons that use touch feed back (highlighting and circling points on the fly and so on). I have looked at proprietary hardware for this and it has been deemed too expencive so i am entertaining the idea of using a Raspberry PI and some form of linux configuration to act as a wireless miracasting reciever that can send the touch inputs back to the staff members laptop.

Windows 10 can do it Out Of the Box, but i'd like something small and wireless to mount on the wall above the screen.